# Go through all possibilities Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists, let's say:

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I would like to create a loop, that would check if each letter in l1 is in l2 (if that's the case I would get " ") or if it's there and on the same position (in that case I would get "Y").

I started with this code (unfortunately I failed). Could you please advise what's missing?

```
     for i in l1:
        for j in range(0,4):
            if l1[j] == l2[j]:
                v = "Y"
            elif i in l2:
                v = "."
            else:
                v = "N"
            text = "".join(v)
```

Which those lists in the example, I would assume to get:

```
text = .NNN
```

I understand that this might be an easy question, but I'm a beginner and it's driving me crazy :)

Comment: There seems to be a bunch of typos in the snippet you (e.g.: what is `w`?) and you also forgot to post what your actual output is

Comment: However `elif i in l2:` will always evalute to `True` because `i` is already defined to be `for i in l2:`

Comment: If you can improve the description of what you're hoping to see for each output case that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, you can use `zip()` to iterate over the two lists simultaneously. Also use `str.join` after the loop:

```py
l1 = ["c", "o", "k", "e"]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

out = []
for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    if a == b:
        out.append("Y")
    elif a in l2:
        out.append(".")
    else:
        out.append("N")

print("".join(out))
```

Prints:

```
.NNN
```

Comment: Zip in this case is not necessary. You only have the iterate over the first list with these operations. This is not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

text = ""
for i in l1:
    if i in l2:
        v = "."
    else:
        v = "N"
    text += v
print(text)
```

First we define `text=""` so that we can just append. Then we loop all the letters in `l1`. We then check if that letter is in `l2`. if it is we add `'.'` to `text` if its not we add `N`. And finally we print the `text`

Comment: This does not add the 'Y'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
ans = ""
for i, val in enumerate(l1):
    if l2[i] == val:
        ans += "Y"
    elif val in l2:
        ans += "."
    else
        ans += "N"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop trough the second array with the operations you are performing. You can simplify your code like this.

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

text = ""
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
        text += "Y"
    elif l1[i] in l2:
        text += "."
    else:
        text += "N"
        
print(text)
```

Looping twice is not needed and therefore not the most efficient solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use python sets.

##### Simple ./N check

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

S = set(l2)

out = ''.join('.' if x in S else 'N' for x in l1)
```

output: `.NNN`

##### more complex ./Y/N check:

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e', 'z']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']

S = set(l2)

out = ''.join(('Y' if l2[i]==x else '.') if x in S else 'N'
              for i, x in enumerate(l1))
```

output: `.NNNY`

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['c', 'o', 'k', 'e']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

text = ""
for char in l1:
  if char in l2:
    index = l1.index(char)
    if char == l2[index]:
      v = "Y"
    else:
      v = "."
  else:
    v = "N"
  text += v

print(text)
```